# failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1 when deploying meteor to android-device

Tags: cordova, meteor

By mistake I completely delete the Android SDK folder.  Previously I have deployed meteor to android devices many times, using cordova/phonegap.  When reinstalling SDK via Android Studio and try to run meteor in device I'm getting this error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1

What could be wrong?  I have checked Android Studio SDK Manager and I have correctly installed:
1) SDK Platform (Build 23)
2) SDK Build Tools **(Build 24.0.1)**
3) SDK Platform Tools (Build 24.0.1)

Also I have correctly set the HOME PATH variable and checked the build-tools folder and the mentioned version is there.  Any advice could be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run from console the command: Android.

It will brings up the android manager (Different to Android studio SDK manager).  It will show that build tools version 24.0.1 is not installed.  Select and install it and problem solved.

Oddly the version installed by Android Studio as 24.0.1 is shown by Android Manager as 24, plain.

p.s.  You should run the Android command inside the sdk/tools directory unless you already have included it in your $PATH variable.

Comment: for some reason even doing this doesn't seem to do it for me -- very confused

Comment: Upss... Did the android manager show the build tools 24.0.1 installed?  The error still the same?

Comment: This is obviously the first place to check, but if it's still not working make sure to try @RogerCarvalho's answer below.

Answer (score 27):

I had this problem too. Even though the build tools were installed using SDK manager, Cordova couldn't locate them. I resolved it by reinstalling the build tools via command line:

```
~/| cd ~/Library/Android/sdk
~/Android/Sdk| ./tools/android list sdk -a | grep "SDK Build-tools"
   4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.1
   ...
~/Android/Sdk| ./tools/android update sdk -a -u -t 4
   ...
```

After doing this, Cordova did recognize the build tools.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me.  This answer did.

Answer (score 1):

1 - npm update -g ionic cordova 
2 - android update sdk -a -u -t 4 
3 - ionic state reset --plugins 
4 - cordova telemetry on 
5 - ionic platform add android 
6 - ionic build android