# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception build ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a IONIC project but I am facing this exception and I am not able to debug the solution for this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\application\Qrioh\plat
forms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\application\Qrioh\platforms\android\bu
ild.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Comment: How about installing the build tools that the error message says are missing?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487341/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-1-when-deploying-meteor-to-android-devi

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Project Structure > Select Module > Properties

Select Build Tools Version same as version selected in Compile Sdk Version.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: But I am using IONIC means i am not able to recognize how can i solve this You have mentioned the path but as such there's no directory in my project

Comment: Which IDE are you using. If it android studio you should find file in the menu tab

Comment: Actually IONIC is hybrid frame work in which we have to script in HTML and just build the app with android SDK. when i was trying to build with Android Studio IDE it is showing me this error